# Error when trying to access Cursor data

Tags: android, cursor

I have a populated Database in my app but I'm having trouble to access data through a returned cursor from the query method.

```
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(MoviesContract.MoviesEntry.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null);

query.moveToFirst();

while (query.isAfterLast() == false){
    Log.d("Test", query.getString(0));
    query.moveToNext();
}
```

I'm doing tests on this block of code. When I execute the Log.d line, this error is raised:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.

This is how I know my database has content:

[image]

What I'm missing? It's my first time dealing with cursors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:

> CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1369680 bytes, free
>   space 596540 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes

I was storing images into the Database.

I'm going to change my architecture to store the image from the webservice with the Offline Caching of Picasso.