# Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I try to learning `SQLite` on Android. This is my first SQL app. So i can not find reason of the these errors.

This is `MainActivity.java :`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
    final ArrayList<String> artNameList =new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Bitmap> artImageList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater =getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_art,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add_art){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);



        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,artNameList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        String Url ="content://com.example.duygu.newartbook.ArtContentProvider";
        Uri artUri =Uri.parse(Url);

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(artUri,null,null,null,"name");

        if(cursor !=null ){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                artNameList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArtContentProvider.NAME)));
                byte[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(ArtContentProvider.IMAGE));
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                artImageList.add(image);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `ArtContentProvider.java`

```
public class ArtContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    //****************************************************CONTENT PROVIDER**************************************************************
    static final String PROVIDER_NAME ="com.example.duygu.newartbook.ArtContentProvider";
    static final String URL ="content://"+PROVIDER_NAME+"/arts";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI =Uri.parse(URL); //Url'nin uri'ye çevirilmesi.


    static final String NAME="name";
    static final String IMAGE="image";
    static final int ARTS=1;
    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    static{
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME,"arts",ARTS);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> ART_PROJECTION_MAP;
    //******************************DATABASE********************************************************************

    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME ="Arts";
    static final String ARTS_TABLE_NAME="arts";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    static final String CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+
            ARTS_TABLE_NAME+"(name TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            "image BLOB NOT NULL);"; // Başka bir yerde kullanmak istediğimiz için bu şekilde tanımlıyoruz.

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_TABLE); //tablomuzu açarak başlıyoruz.

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) { // herhangi bir upgrade durumunda tablo silinip yenisi oluşturuluyor.
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ARTS_TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
    //******************************DATABASE********************************************************************
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context= getContext();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper =new DatabaseHelper(context); // helper çağrıldı
        sqLiteDatabase=databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //yazılabilir olması için





        return (sqLiteDatabase != null); //sqlitedatabase boş değilse true döner. Boolena çevirmiş olduk.
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projections, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] strings1, @Nullable String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(ARTS_TABLE_NAME);
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case ARTS:
                sqLiteQueryBuilder.setProjectionMap(ART_PROJECTION_MAP);
                break;
            default:
        }

        if(sortOrder == null || sortOrder.matches("")){
            sortOrder=NAME; //isme göre diz
        }

        Cursor cursor =sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(sqLiteDatabase,projections,selection,strings1,null,null,sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri); // uri da bir değişiklik olursa takip etmek için kullandığımız yöntem.
        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {
        long rowID= sqLiteDatabase.insert(ARTS_TABLE_NAME,"",contentValues);
        if (rowID>0){
            Uri newUri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI,rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(newUri,null);
            return newUri;
        }

        throw new SQLException("Failed");


    }

    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And This my errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.duygu.newartbook, PID: 26354
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.duygu.newartbook/com.example.duygu.newartbook.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                      at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                      at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                      at com.example.duygu.newartbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
```

Comment: I see you're storing images in your SQLite database. That's generally not a good idea, as explained by the duplicate I'm about to link to. `Cursors` can only store a limited amount of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to access Cursor data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990550/error-when-trying-to-access-cursor-data)

Comment: You're also missing a `cursor.moveToFirst()`, which is usually good practice.

Comment: but i can not open app i have a runtime error if i remove this string i can open the app but doesnt make sense. String Url ="content://com.example.duygu.newartbook.ArtContentProvider";

Comment: No, it relates to the `byte[]` array you're trying to retrieve with `getBlob()`. Does it still crash if you limit your query to just th e`ArtContentProvider.NAME` column?

Comment: yes it still crush

Comment: Same stacktrace error?

Comment: yes same error. If i change this line i can not see any error: String Url ="content://com.example.duygu.newartbook.ArtContentProvider";

Comment: Oww if i try on emulator it works. Emulator 5.0 but my phone 6.0 is this a reason ?